# Multiple deployments of virtual machines/instances

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, puppet, juju

Which one is better to go with.. Juju or Puppet/Chef? Why?

I want to start multiple deployments at the same time, to avoid making the corresponding the server setup again and again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need, every software has its own strengths and weaknesses:

Juju encapsulates services - a charm defines all the ways the service needs to expose or consume config data to/from other services. How a charm does that is the charm's business. It can use any tool from shell scripts to Chef in solo mode, to do that.

Juju orchestrates provisioning - juju keeps track of the resources it has available to it, and can add or remove them as needed.

Juju makes sharing easy - anyone can contribute a charm to the Juju Charm Store; these charms are vetted and peer reviewed by the Juju community.

My recommendation is to go with none of them.. it is Docker's age, a simple tool that manages all of your resources in an easy, fast and reliable way. It is also supported by all cloud providers, so you can simply go and launch your Docker VM on Azure and play with it the way you want.

http://www.docker.com/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-docker-machine/

Comment: thanks Ghassan, that's a pretty clear answer. I'll dig more into docker it seems a nice software to use. it's the 2nd time you help, appreciated.

Comment: Am sure u'll like it.. good luck with that